# Optimizing Script Transformation in SSIS 2005

Tags: ssis

I've got an SSIS 2005 data flow with a DT_TEXT column on which I need to perform some string replacements.  I tried doing this in a Derived Column task but such an expression limits the size of the column to 4000 characters.  Otherwise, a truncation error will occur.

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE((DT_STR, 4000, 1252) [COMMENT],"&#38;","&"),"&#09;","\t"),"&#10;","\n")
```

So I've turned to a script transformation to do the same string replacements as shown here:

```
Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

    Dim blobData() As Byte = Row.COMMENT.GetBlobData(0, CInt(Row.COMMENT.Length))
    Dim blobString As String = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(blobData)

    blobString.Replace("&#38;", "&").Replace("&#09;", "\t").Replace("&#10;", "\n")

    Row.SCRUBBEDCOMMENT.AddBlobData(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(blobString))

End Sub
```

This works fine but it's sooooo slow.  Is there anything I can do to speed it up?  Or can this be done in an SSIS expression without truncation?

Thanks,

Bill

Comment: Why don't you do that transformation after loadidng your data to db? If only you don't need this already transfromed string in your package, this would be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured out a quick way to speed things up... just call the AddBlobData method only when a replacement is made.  In my case, I don't expect there to be many replacements made.  This definitely speeds up the transformation.  Hope this helps others.

Bill